# Recycler Adapter in fragment returns null on first instantiation

Tags: android, firebase

I have 3 fragments in my activity as follows CHAT,FRIENDS and STATUS,The first one is empty and the rest of the two have data. When the app is run for the first time and i navigate to the last fragment(STATUS),it shows nothing but when i navigate to the first fragment(CHAT) and back to the last(STATUS), the data loads correctly.

Note-The data in the second fragments loads correctly when opened for the first time.

please i need your help i am new to android development

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_status_, container, false);

        friendsRequest = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("FriendsRequest");
        mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        mdatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        CurrentUser_id = mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid();
        return view;

    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(@NonNull View view, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);
        requestview = view.findViewById(R.id.requestView);
        LinearLayoutManager linearLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getContext());
        requestview.setLayoutManager(linearLayoutManager);
        requestview.setHasFixedSize(true);

        initadapter();
    }

    public void initadapter() {
        friendsRequest.child(CurrentUser_id).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                    if (ds.child("request_type").getValue().toString().equals("received")) {
                        final String key = ds.getKey();

                        final DatabaseReference checkData = mdatabase.child("Users");

                        checkData.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                                if (dataSnapshot.hasChild(key)) {

                                    checkData.child(key).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                            list.add(dataSnapshot.getValue(Users.class));
                                        }

                                        @Override
                                        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                        }
                                    });
                                }
                            }

                            @Override
                            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

                            }
                        });


                    }
                }

                requesAdapter = new RequesAdapter(list, Status_Frag.this);
                requestview.setAdapter(requesAdapter);
                int size = requesAdapter.getItemCount();
                String asa = String.valueOf(size);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), asa, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It will be better for you to use Firebase RecylerAdapter .